# If $A$ is not totally bounded then $A$ has an infinite subset $B$ homeomorphic to a discrete space

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, compactness, equivalent-metrics

If $A$ is not totally bounded then $A$ has an infinite subset $B$ homeomorphic to a discrete space.

My approach since $A$ is not totally bounded we can find $\epsilon>0$ and a sequence $x_n$ suchthat $d(x_m, x_n)> \epsilon$. Then  what to do? any idea?

Answer (score 7):

Just show that $\{x_n:n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ is discrete, i.e. every singleton is an open set.

For each $n\in\mathbb{N}$, show that $B(x_n,\epsilon)$ only contains $x_n$.

Comment: how to show this?